# Prove that $\omega$ is not successor ordinal

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

Prove that $\omega$ is not successor ordinal ?

I assumed that $\omega$ is successor ordinal, meaning there is ordinal $\beta$ such that $S(\beta) = \omega$ meaning $\beta \cup \{ \beta \} = \omega$

Resulting that $\beta \in \omega $ so $ \beta$ is finite, but how to proceed ?

Comment: If $\beta$ is finite then $S(\beta)$ is finite...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Usually in set theory natural numbers (elements of $\omega$) are defined as the sets that belong to every class that contains the empty set and is closed under the successor operation. At that stage the concept "finite" has not been treated yet.

Comment: What's your formal definition of $\omega$? If it is 'the least non-zero limit ordinal, there is nothing to do. If it is 'the least ordinal which is an infinite set', it suffices to note what @David said: the successor of a finite ordinal is again a finite set.

Comment: @StefanMesken If the order that I have in mind is used then it is the set $\omega:=\{n\in a\mid n\text{ is a natural number}\}$ where $a$ is a set that contains the empty set and is closed under the successor operation (such set exists by the grace of axiom INF), and a natural number is a set that is element of all sets that have these properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show $\beta$ is a maximum element of $\omega.$
Thus a contradiction.

Comment: It is possible that this answer only shifts the question to: "prove that $\omega$ has no maximal elements". Unfortunately the OP has not answered the question posed by @StefanMesken.

Answer (score -1):

First prove that $n\notin n$ for every $n\in\omega$.

For that define $b:=\{n\in\omega\mid n\notin n\}\subseteq\omega$ and prove by induction that $b=\omega$.

That comes to proving that $\varnothing\in b$ and $n\in b\implies n\cup\{n\}\in b$, allowing the conclusion that next to $b\subseteq\omega$ also $\omega\subseteq b$.

Now if $\omega=\beta\cup\{\beta\}$ then $\beta\in\omega$ and then also $\omega=\beta\cup\{\beta\}\in\omega$.

This because $\omega$ is closed under the successor operation.

But from $\omega\in\omega$ you can conclude now that $\omega\notin\omega$ and a contradiction is found.

Comment: Be so kind to explain if you downvote my answer. I want to learn from my mistakes.

Comment: Your proof is vacuous for, by regularity, x not in x, for all x.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Firstly, thank you very much for your comment! Secondly I disagree. An axiom cannot make a proof vacuous. Zermelo gave a very nice proof of the theorem that any set can be well ordered without using the axiomscheme of replacement. Is that proof vacuous by your standards? My answer simply shows that the statement can be proved without using the axiom of regularity. By any proof of a theorem it is a good thing to ask: "which axioms are actually needed here?" And a proof that does it with less axioms is in my view superior.